# Create a post with multiple tags and categories using the WordPress REST API in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to create a wordpress post with multiple categories and multiple tags using the REST API. My script is working fine it seems. The Problem is that the post is created with only **one** tag and **one** category. It looks like it's always the lowest ID, which is used by WP.

```
import requests
import json

# URL and auth
wp_url = "http://FQDN/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
auth = ("MyUser", "MyPassword")


# Post params
data = {
  "categories": [32, 30, 33],
  "tags": [121, 95, 117, 109],
  "title": "This is the Title",
  "content": "Content Lorem Ipsum",
  "status": "publish",
}

# Post
wp_create_response = requests.post(wp_url, auth=auth, data=data)

# Check if successfull
if wp_create_response.status_code == 201:
  post_id = wp_create_response.json()["id"]
  post_tagids = wp_create_response.json()["tags"]
  post_categoryids = wp_create_response.json()["categories"]

  print(f"Successfully created Post! ID: {post_id}")
  print(f"Post Tag IDs: {post_tagids}")
  print(f"Post Category IDs: {post_categoryids}")

else:
  print("Error: " + wp_create_response.text)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> Successfully created Post! ID: 54
>>> Post Tag IDs: [109]
>>> Post Category IDs: [33]
```

Is this a Wordpress bug or am I doing domething wrong here?

Wordpress Version 6.1.1, Python 3.9

Comment: not an expert here but did you check from the actual backend if the post has assigned tags/categories anyway even thought the response did not show those ?

Comment: yes I did. Same result. Only one tag and one category

Answer (score 3):

Argh... I figured it out. The Wordpress API reference is misleading.
The API is not expecting (although accepting) an array of elements. It expects a comma-separated string.

```
# Post params
data = {
  "categories": "32, 30, 33",
  "tags": "121, 95, 117, 109",
  "title": "This is the Title",
  "content": "Content Lorem Ipsum",
  "status": "publish",
 }
```

This is working as expected.